# Is there a way to get the values of all rows of a specific column in Flask?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm new in Flask and I woudl to know if there's a way to get the values of all rows of a specific column

This is my model class:

```
class Documents(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    date_posted = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable=False)
```

and I would to get all rows of **title** column. In this way I get the whole Documents object with all column.

```
documents = Documents.query.all()
```

How could I do that?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can get it with `session.query(Documents.title).all()`.

EDIT:
After some extra information, you can use `db.session.query(Documents.title).all()` to achieve what you want.

Comment: It gives me *AttributeError: 'SecureCookieSession' object has no attribute 'query'*

Comment: @GiorgioGiò try `db.session.query` then. Also see here: https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/quickstart/

Comment: @GiorgioGiò Nice! I'll edit my original answer then!